# Liquids that change refractive index with magnetic fields

Tags: optics

I am trying to find out liquids that would change their refractive index with applied electromagnetic field. Do they exist? I cannot seem to find a lot of research on it.

A super basic example is water with salt and when EM field applied change of ion positions in the water result in a refractive index change. Probably this is a bad example but I am looking for good ones. Particularly, I am wondering why people didn't implement liquid lenses that can change their index in a matter of nSecs.

Comment: Look up Kerr Medium, Pockels effect, Faraday rotation (and other forms of *gyroelectromagnetism*). The field of nonlinear optics is wholly about the modulation of refractive index of the medium by a propagating electromagnetic material, and thus an effect on its own propagation. Green tea has a famously high Kerr constant and was widely used in early nonlinear optics experiments.

Comment: Could you comment more on the green tea please? It sounds fascinating

Comment: Isn't the problem with these 2nd order effects such as Kerr is you need hundreds of volts for a small effect? Liquid crystals molecules don't change refractive index themselves but they reorientate resulting in a refractive index change for the bulk material.